# Getting files onto Fresh Install of Server 2008 "The Right Way"?

Tags: windows-server-2008, best-practices, upload

I am still fairly new to windows server administration. I have a Server 2008 r2 ec2 instance running and will need to bring a new one up every so often. I like that it is locked down by default, but is there a "preferred" way to get zip files or applications on to the server?

I don't want to go in and start adding sites to allow exceptions for trying to download stuff. I also don't "need" FTP so I didn't want to setup the ftp server. Is there anything built in to windows similar to SSH's scp which I use in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you maintain an EBS volume with all the files you'll need to get new server instances up and running? Whenever you need to bring up a new server, mount the volume and copy the files over.

Comment: That requires way to much logic. lol. I think I will do that, great idea.